# How to get all logical operator token in a rule

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have a problem in getting all operator token in a rule. Such as if my input is **(states = failed) and (states1 = nominal) or (states2 = nominal)**, then I want to get **"and"/"or"**. I already have a grammar that can parse my input, but words like **'and'** and **'or'** are keywords in my grammar. So that they can show up in the parse tree but they didn't match a rule.

[image]

I want to finish it by Listener method, but I don't know how to get these tokens.
**My lexer file:**

```
lexer grammar TransitionLexer;

BOOLEAN: 'true' | 'false';
IF: 'if';
THEN: 'then';
ELSE: 'else';

NAME: (ALPHA | CHINESE | '_')(ALPHA | CHINESE | '_'|DIGIT)*;

ALPHA: [a-zA-Z];
CHINESE: [\u4e00-\u9fa5];

NUMBER: INT | REAL;
INT: DIGIT+
    |'(-'DIGIT+')';
REAL: DIGIT+ ('.' DIGIT+)?
    | '(-' DIGIT+ ('.' DIGIT+)? ')';
fragment DIGIT: [0-9];

OPCOMPARE: '='|'>='|'<='|'!='|'>'|'<';
WS: [ \t\n\r]+ ->skip;
SL_COMMENT:  '/*' .*? '*/' ->skip;
```

**My grammar file:**

```
grammar TransitionCondition;
import TransitionLexer;
@parser::header{
    import java.util.*;
}
@parser:: members{
    private List<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();

    public boolean isKeyWord(){
        return keywords.contains(getCurrentToken().getText());
    }

    public List<String> getKeywords(){
        return keywords;
    }
}

condition : stat+ EOF;
stat : expr;

expr: pair (('and' | 'or') pair)*
    | '(' pair ')';

pair: '(' var OPCOMPARE value ')'   # keyValuePair
      | booleanExpr # booleanPair
      | BOOLEAN         # plainBooleanPair
      ;

var: localStates    # localVar
     | globalStates # globalVar
     | connector        # connectorVar
     ;
localStates: NAME;
globalStates: 'Top' ('.' brick)+ '.' NAME;
connector: brick '.' NAME;

value: {isKeyWord()}? userDefinedValue
         |basicValue
         ;

userDefinedValue: NAME;
basicValue: arithmeticExpr | booleanExpr;

booleanExpr: booleanExpr op=('and' | 'or') booleanExpr
                       | BOOLEAN
                       | relationExpr
                       | 'not' booleanExpr
                       | '(' booleanExpr ')'
                       ;
relationExpr: arithmeticExpr
                      | arithmeticExpr OPCOMPARE arithmeticExpr
                      ;
arithmeticExpr: arithmeticExpr op=('*'|'/') arithmeticExpr
                           | arithmeticExpr op=('+'|'-') arithmeticExpr
                           | 'min' '(' arithmeticExpr (',' arithmeticExpr)* ')'
                           | 'max' '(' arithmeticExpr (',' arithmeticExpr)* ')'
                           | globalStates
                           | connector
                           | localStates
                           | NUMBER
                           | '(' arithmeticExpr ')'
                           ;
brick: NAME;
```

My Input file t.expr with content: `(states = failed) and (states1 = nominal) or (states2 = nominal)`

> I get the tree in Command line using 'grun'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [label](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/parser-rules.md#alternative-labels) your parser rule `expr`:

```
expr
 : pair (operators+=('and' | 'or') pair)* #logicalExpr
 | '(' pair ')'                           #parensExpr
 ;
```

your (generated) listener class will contain these methods:

```
void enter_logicalExpr(TransitionConditionParser.LogicalExprContext ctx);

void enter_parensExpr(TransitionConditionParser.ParensExprContext ctx);
```

Inside `enter_logicalExpr` you can find the `and`/`or` tokens in the `java.util.List` from the context: `ctx.operators`.

Comment: Thanks!! It works! Actually, I tried `pair (operators=('and' | 'or') pair)*` before, I didn't use '+=', So I can only get one op. Thanks.